# How to add to a variables name a variable? JAVA

Tags: java, string, variables, int

Is there a way to add to a variables name a variable? for example `int number = 1;` and `String tree;` and know I would like to add the number to the Strings name so it would make tree1

Comment: You want an array, list, or map.

Comment: You can't do that in Java. However you can use a `Map` to store the mapping of variables.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005696/int-variable-name-as-string

Comment: OK how do I do a the map?? @RohitJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, basically:

- If you want to have a collection of values indexed by contiguous numbers, use a `List` or an array.
- If you want to have a collection of values indexed by something else (e.g. a string), use a `Map`.

Any time you find yourself wanting variable names of `foo1`, `foo2` etc, consider using a collection instead. It's almost *always* a better approach.

You *can* fetch fields (but not local variables) by name using reflection ([`Class.getDeclaredField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29)) but that's very rarely a useful approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

```
int x = 1;
String tree + x = "tree1" // not valid
```

But you can use a list or a map and populate the item or key after you do the concat operation.

Examples:

```
final List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){    
    values.add("tree" + i);
}

final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

String[] trees = {"Apple Tree", "Banana Tree", "Grape Tree", "Orange Tree", "Binary Tree"};

for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){    
    map.put("tree" + i, trees[i - 1]);
}
```

Comment: "Cannot" is a bit strong, given the existence of reflection.

Comment: @AndyThomas Isn't it reassignment of value in run time rather than creating variable name with another variable's value in compile time?

Comment: Reflection allows both getting and setting the value of a field. "Cannot" would be appropriate if the OP is asking how to create a new variable at runtime, but would be a bit strong it the OP is asking how to access a field by a dynamic name at runtime.

Comment: @AndyThomas In that case, yes I agree.. but I was answering the question - "Is there a way to add to a variables name a variable?"

Comment: The question can be interpreted in more than one way. We're in agreement on the facts.